# Libgdx MainMenuScreen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am Trying to learn to use the libgdx framework. Like the tutorial (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ExtendedSimpleApp) on the website of libgdx describes, i tried to set up a little main menu. I have imported all classes that are needed, but at line 29 there is always the error: "MainMenuScreen can not be resolved to a type".
Here is the source code:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import java.awt.SplashScreen;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;



public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;
private BitmapFont font;

    @Override
public void create() {      
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    //Use LibGDX's default Arial font.
    font = new BitmapFont();
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
```

}

Comment: Did you create a class called MainMenuScreen that implements Screen ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MainMenuScreen is not a standard-class, if you read further in the tutorial you have linked you see that they created an additional class "MainMenuScreen", just create another class named "MainMenuScreen" and add the code from the tutorial there.

If this is your first time with java you might want to google some java tutorials to the learn the fundementals of java and oop first before you use some external libraries ;)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!  I know how java works, but i didn´t do something with android for a long time:D  P.s. I am no native english speaker, so the tutorials are not so easy to understand for me;)

Comment: @BigT This is actually not Android specific at all. Libgdx is a cross-platform game engine and that problem you have is not anyhow Android related.

Comment: as always recomended take a look at the Steigert blog and youll understand the system fast: http://steigert.blogspot.de/

Comment: This seems to be a good answer. If you agree @BigT, you should consider accepting it. "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked." - from http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

you need to make a class which extends game class of libgdx.

```
public class MainClass extends Game
```

then in your create methodof mainclass you have to set the screen.

```
setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
```

and in your mainmenuclass you have to implement screen class of libgdx.

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen
```

and you have to make a constructor like this

```
public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.game = game;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, scrw, scrh);//scrw is your screen width,scrh is screen height
    camera.update();
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(MainMenuScreen.this);}
```

i think this will work ...

Answer (score 1):

To start learning libGDX check out this project: https://github.com/edesdan/libgdx-playground. Maybe it could help you to do the first steps into this world.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic concept is not clear.
To use different screens in a  single application, you have to extend the `Game` class.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game implements ApplicationListener{}
```

To choose a different screen, call:

```
setScreen(new XYZScreen(this));
```

`this` refer to object of `MyGdxGame`.

Now you have to make a new class of XYZ name. Then do whatever you want on your new screen.

Answer (score 1):

if you want use of class Screen you should extend mainclass from class Game
if you use screen u can't use applicationlistener no more because in Screen you have all application Listener functions overrided  ...

all you have to do is move your code in application listener to "MainMenuScreen"

then you set the screen when creating class Mainclass to "MainMenuScreen"

public class MainClass extends Game {

```
@Override
public void create() {
    setScreen(new MainMenuScreen());
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually used Screens in a small project that I've done, here's the code for one of my screens.

```
package com.sample.Main;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Mainmenu implements Screen {

    MainGame game;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    Mainmenu(MainGame g){
        game = g;
        batch = g.batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {


    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

And here for the main game code that runs the screen:

```
package com.sample.Main;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MainGame extends Game {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Screen mainscreen;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        mainscreen = new Mainmenu(this);
        setScreen(mainscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```